# MS-Access 2016 NavigationControl (Tabs) not displaying

Tags: ms-access, vba

The NavigationControl (Tabs) does not show in an Access 2016 database, only for some users, after the first tab has been selected.

We have 19 users, all running Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 and MS-Access 2016 Runtime. The database contains a central Navigation Form with 8 tabs in the Horizontal Tabs layout, forming a bar above the navigation sub-form. 17 users have no problem with the database, but 3 users have the following problem:

After logging in to the database, the Navigation Form is presented, complete with horizontal tabs for selection. Once a selection has been made (does not matter which tab) the appropriate form is correctly displayed, but the NavigationControl (Tab Bar) disappears.

I have checked all of the users' screen resolutions. There is no correlation with the problem. I have 2 users, both with 1920x1080 resolution; one has the problem and one does not.

I have scoured all the forums, including this one, but I cannot find anything similar.

I tried using VBA in the Navigation Form's Current as follows:

```
With Me!NavigationControl0
        .Visible = True
        .Height = 1.032
        .Width = 43.817
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
        .HorizontalAnchor = acHorizontalAnchorBoth
        .VerticalAnchor = acVerticalAnchorBoth
    End With
```

The problem persists. Has anyone witnessed this and come up with a solution?

TDP - User with problem logged on to my machine (known good) with no issues. Conversely, I logged on to his machine; problem remained. Problem is machine-specific.

**Edit 07 Jun 18**
I found that one affected user had two versions of the runtime installed (2010 and 2016) and that the file association was with 2010. I uninstalled the 2010 version and re-associated the database with 2016. It did not cure it.

I also found that my statement that all tabs were affected was incorrect. Two of the tabs show forms that are in what I think is a datasheet view, i.e. displaying a table layout. The NavigationControl (tabs) displays correctly for these. The other tabs are the traditional Form View and the NavigationControl for these disappears.

For each tab, in the Enter event, is `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`. Nothing else.
For the two affected tabs there is code under the Click event:

```
Private Sub NavigationButton9_Click() ' Enquiry Form
    DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "Enquiry", "Navigation Form.NavigationSubform", , , acFormEdit
    Me.[NavigationSubform].SetFocus
    Forms![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].Form.FilterOn = False
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub
```

It is the only difference I can find but I cannot see what would invoke the NavigationControl to disappear.

BTW: The Navigation Control itself has no events assigned in any of the categories (Macro, Expression or Code)

**Edit 2 - 07 Jun 18**.
I added a button to the Navigation Form header and used its Click event to display a message box listing the Visibility, Height, Width, Top, Left, H Anchor, V Anchor, Span, Display When and Enabled variables for the NavigationControl. Even with the NavigationControl missing all the variables are OK.

It seems, from relative positioning on the screen, that the sub-form is moving upwards. Could it be that it is lying over the front of the NavigationControl, obscuring it?

**Edit 3 - 07 Jun 18**.
Monitored the .Top variable of the NavigationSubForm. The value is the same, regardless of whether the tabs are there or not; yet the sub-form (or form?) has physically moved upwards (I guess, to obscure the tags).

Comment: Have you tried getting one of your 3 users with the issue to try on a machine where it's working?

Comment: @TDP This my first question. Just noticed that I had answered in edit, which is wrong. User with problem logged on to my machine (known good) with no issues. Conversely, I logged on to his machine; problem remained. Problem is machine-specific.

Comment: Good news. Nothing wrong with your code! Do you have a dedicated IT Pro type team you could delegate the issue to? Who builds the machines?

Comment: @TDP Unfortunately, no. We outsource that.